# Proving there are no intermediate normal extensions

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $E/F$ be a finite extension and $L \supseteq E$ an splitting field of a polynomial $g \in F[x]$ such that every irreducible factor of $g$ in $F[X]$ has a root in $E$. I need to prove $L/F$ is a norma closure (doesn't exists normal intermediate extensions).

Since $L$ is splitting field of a polynomial en $F[x]$ it follows that $L/F$ is normal.

Now if $F \subseteq K\subseteq L$ is a field such that $K/F$ is normal I want to prove $K=L$ but I don't know how to, any suggetion would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The strategy in the last paragraph is mistaken: consider $F = \mathbf Q$, $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})$, and $L = K(\sqrt{3})$.  In the last paragraph you are giving up too much information about your original problem.  Show your $L$ is a splitting field over your $F$ of $g(x)$.  What do you mean by "is Galois closure"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Splitting field of separable polynomial is Galois extension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124819/splitting-field-of-separable-polynomial-is-galois-extension)

Comment: I realized that my question was all over the place, I only need to show the property of being normal. Still I'm not sure how to conclude